# How do I horizontally align all the fields in my form?

Tags: html, css

My fields are not vertically aligned. What can I do so that they are aligned as shown in below image?

[image]

```css
#application-form label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#application-form input, select {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#application-submit {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#checkbox-agree {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
    <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
    <label>Make and model: *
        <input type="text" name="what_make">
    </label>
    <label>How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *
        <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required>
    </label>
    <label>How many applicants? *
        <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <label>Title:*
        <select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option><option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: what you mean by vertically aligning? did you mean the horizontal alignment??

Comment: I heard that using line-height can work.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use **flexbox** to align the input fields to the right of your label tags.

**display**: flex -> *tells to use flexbox*

**flex-flow**: row nowrap -> *puts items on horizontal line and does not wrap when resizing to smaller window*

**justify-content**: space-between -> *pushes content to either side of the width of the element*

**width**: 80% -> *random width I chose for the example, you can play around with this to fit your design.*

Checkout the updated code below, I left out the CSS that you don't seem to need to get the desired result.

Also, it's nice to use rem instead of px because they scale.

Very handy **flexbox**  [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by css-tricks

```css
#application-form label {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#application-form input, select {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
    <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
    <label>Make and model: *
        <input type="text" name="what_make">
    </label>
    <label>How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *
        <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required>
    </label>
    <label>How many applicants? *
        <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <label>Title:*
        <select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option><option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to give your labels a `for` attribute and your inputs an `id`.

Also I would recommend you to wrap each "line" in a div. This is the way I prefer it. The code below shows you how to do it without the divs.

```css
label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input, select{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 2%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
    <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
    <label for="what_make">Make and model: *</label>
    <input type="text" name="what_make" id="what_make">
    <label for="what_pre_approved">How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *</label>
    <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" id="what_pre_approved" required="required">
    <label for="what_how_many">How many applicants? *</label>
    <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required="required">
        <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <label for="contact_title">Title:*</label>
    <select name="contact_title" id="contact_title" required="required">
        <option value="mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="miss">Miss</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Using input inside label is perfectly valid: "Alternatively, you can nest the <input> directly inside the <label>, in which case the for and id attributes are not needed because the association is implicit". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify your html and css code a bit to get your desired result. Try this code.

```
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
    <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
    <label><span>Make and model: *</span>
        <input type="text" name="what_make">
    </label>
    <label><span>How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *</span>
        <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required>
    </label>
    <label><span>How many applicants? *</span>
        <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <label><span>Title:*</span>
        <select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option><option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>

#application-form label {
  display: block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#application-form label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}
#application-form input, select {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#application-submit {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#checkbox-agree {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. this may help you. I had used tables.

```css
#application-form label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
   
}
#application-form input, select {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#application-form td {
    vertical-align: initial;
}
#application-submit {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#checkbox-agree {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
 <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label>Make and model: 
            </label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <lable><input type="text" name="what_make"> </lable>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label>How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *
            </label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <lable> <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required> </lable>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label>How many applicants? *
            </label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <lable><select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        </select> </lable>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td>
            <label>Title:*
            </label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <lable><select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option><option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select></lable>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use table in the form:

```css
#application-form table {
  width: 100%;
}

#application-form table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}

#application-form table tr td:first-child {
  width: 30%;
}

#application-form label {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#application-form input,
select {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#application-submit {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#checkbox-agree {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
  <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="what_make">Make and model: *</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="what_make"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="what_pre_approved">How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *</label></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="what_how_many">How many applicants? *    </label></td>
      <td>
        <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <hr>
  <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Title:*</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option>
            <option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Tables shouldn't be used for layout.

Answer (score -1):

Add `position:absolute; left: 400;` into 
`#application-from input ,select { margin-left: 50px; }`

```css
#application-form label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#application-form input, select {
    margin-left: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 400px;
}
#application-submit {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#checkbox-agree {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="application-thank-you/" method="POST" id="application-form">
    <h2>What are you wanting to buy?</h2>
    <label>Make and model: *
        <input type="text" name="what_make">
    </label>
    <label>How much do you want to be pre approved for?: *
        <input type="number" name="what_pre_approved" required>
    </label>
    <label>How many applicants? *
        <select name="what_how_many" id="what_how_many" required>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <h2>Contact Details - Applicant 1</h2>
    <label>Title:*
        <select name="contact_title" required>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="ms">Ms</option><option value="miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Absolute position is problematic and unnecessary.